# How to make a broken y-Axis chart in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I use a broken Y-Axis in Microsoft Excel like in this image below?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can. If it is for just one or two plots, then you could edit them in an image editing software before putting them in your final report.

Comment: From the sample graph you've shown, I surmise you've read Jon Peltier's advice against doing this. But there's some [discussion here](https://superuser.com/questions/150533/how-to-break-the-y-axis-in-an-excel-sheet/363514) that you might find helpful. See sancho's answer. BTW, this question is a duplicate of the one in the link above.